# JQuery and AJAX post to php without reloading page in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I'm developing a plugin in Wordpress and am having difficulty trying to post data to a separate PHP file using Ajax without reloading the page. On the backend, the PHP file is relying on `if( isset() )` to execute an SQL query. On the client side, the user should see individual records fadeOut and a message that records were successfully deleted.

UPDATE: The javascript is working so far, once the form button is clicked, the correct `div`-s fade in and fade out. However, the PHP file is not getting any value posted to it, as tested with a `var_dump`.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!-- problem: when setting "action" to a url, that page is automatically loaded. I want to stay on the existing page. -->
        <form action='' id='form-delete-assoc' method='post'>
    <input name='remove_all' type='submit' id='remove-all' value='Remove All'></input>
    </form>
```

**JQUERY:** (updated with some fixes suggested by answerers)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr.assoc_row').show();
        $('#settings-removed-msg').hide();
        $('#new-assoc-msg').hide();
        $('#formdeleteassoc').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo $cb_t2c_remove_all_url; ?>',
                data: {removeall: 'yes'
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#settings-removed-msg').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('tr.assoc_row').fadeOut('fast');
                    }
            });
        });

        $('#formsavesettings').submit(function(){
            $('#new-assoc-msg').fadeIn('fast');
            });
    });
</script>
```

**remove_all.php:**

```
<?php
//remove_all.php

global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

$remove_var_dump = $_POST['removeall']; //returning NULL
var_dump($remove_var_dump);

if ( isset( $_POST['removeall'] ) ){
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$prefix."cb_tags2cats");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Try adding return false; after your Ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others said, you need to either `return false` or use `preventDefault()`.  You should also move your calls to `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` into the `success` callback.  If you don't and the request is unsuccessful for some reason, the user may be misled into thinking it *was* successful.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr.assoc_row').show();
        $('#settings-removed-msg').hide();

        $('#form-delete-assoc').submit(function(e){

            // prevent the form from submitting normally
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/delete-assoc.php', // Relative paths work fine
                data: { removeall: 'delete-all' },
                success: function(){
                  $('tr.assoc_row').fadeOut('slow');
                  $('#settings-removed-msg').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. I'm wondering if I have my JQuery articulated too early in the plugin. Maybe it's not passing anything to $_POST['form-delete-assoc'] because the script precedes the form. Also, do you have any idea about whether I need to use the full url for post action in Wordpress, or will it assume that delete-assoc.php is in the same folder? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Just saw your comment on relative paths.

Comment: If you're using `submit` the script has to come after the form is rendered.  However, if you use `.on( 'click' '#form-delete-assoc', function(){} )` it doesn't matter where the script is called from (before or after the form is rendered): http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Your form submit event needs to return false, to stop the form from actually submitting.

```
 $('#form-delete-assoc').submit(function(){
   ... rest of your code here...

   return false;
 }
```

Comment: That fixed the first problem, of having the form load when I didn't want it to. Thank you! The only other issue is that the $_POST variable in the php file is not setting. I tried to tie it to the form ID (i.e., if(isset($_POST['form-delete-assoc'])) ) and the input ID (i.e., if(isset($_POST['form-delete-assoc'])) ), and neither works. Somewhere between using the ajax to set the $_POST variable and actually checking if it is set in the php, the information is not getting sent.

Comment: JQuery will not automatically put the form data in the ajax request. You have to do it manually yourself, by adding it into the `data` value sent to the ajax call.

Comment: So the script shows that the ajax call sets the data manually with a label of 'removeall' and a value of 'yes'. Yet, the PHP code, which triggers on isset ( $_POST['removeall'] ) is not executing: `if ( isset( $_POST['removeall'] ) ){
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$prefix."cb_tags2cats");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

to post data to a separate php page without reloading current (parent or top) page, create a hidden iFrame and use it as the submit target.  this type of solution allows posting and retrieving json responses.  this snippet uploads a file to a php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; //'upload_target' is the name of the iframe
    }
}
window.onload=init;
</script>
</head><body>
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

this tutorial explains the process step by step ->
http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

follow up on how to parse the response ->
http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/response_data.php